# Deleting items from ListView in android

Tags: android, database, listview

I'm having trouble refreshing my ListView after deleting an item from the database. My app lets you select an entry in a list which opens a new activity and displays information based on which item you click (I am passing the list item ID) and there's a delete button in that activity. On deletion, the entry which was preceding the selected one gets deleted from the ListView and the information is blank when the replacing item is selected.

Can anyone give me some insight as to what is going on? Everyone suggests using  `notifySetDataChanged()` but that isn't working for me.

Here is the MainActivity:

```
package com.example.msdproject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.util.Log;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public ArrayList<String> data_list=new ArrayList<String>();
    DBManager db =  new DBManager(this);
    public ArrayAdapter<String> concertList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addConcertButton);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddArtist.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        try {
            db.open();
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        addData();
        //db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        addData();

    }

    public void addData()
    {
        data_list.clear();            
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        Cursor c = db.getAllConcerts();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                data_list.add(c.getString(0));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        concertList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data_list);
        listView.setAdapter(concertList);

    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Intent i =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewArtist.class);
        i.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Here is the ViewArtist Activity:

```
package com.example.msdproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ViewArtist extends Activity
{

    DBManager db = new DBManager(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_artist);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final long num = intent.getLongExtra("id", 1);

        Button update = (Button)findViewById(R.id.updateConcertButton);
        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(ViewArtist.this, UpdateArtist.class);
                i.putExtra("id", num);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        String name;
        String venue;
        String date;
        String comments;

        try {
            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getConcert(num + 1);
            //The reason I have num + 1 is because List Item 1 has a ROW_ID of 0
            if (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    name = (c.getString(1));
                    venue = (c.getString(2));
                    date = (c.getString(3));
                    comments = (c.getString(4));

                    TextView nameTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewName);
                    TextView titleTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewTitle);
                    TextView venueTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewVenue);
                    TextView dateTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewDate);
                    TextView commentsTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewComments);

                    nameTxt.setText(" " + name);
                    titleTxt.setText("ROW_ID: " + String.valueOf(num));
                    venueTxt.setText(" " + venue);
                    dateTxt.setText(" " + date);
                    commentsTxt.setText(" " + comments);

                    Button del = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deleteConcertButton);
                    del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            db.deleteConcert(num);
                            Toast.makeText(ViewArtist.this, "Concert Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the DBManager class that contains the code for deleting a database entry:

```
package com.example.msdproject;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class DBManager {

    public static final String COL_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_VENUE = "venue";
    public static final String COL_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COL_COMMENTS = "comments";

    private static final String DB_NAME = "Concerts";
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "Concert_Info";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DB_CREATE =
            "create table " + DB_TABLE + 
    " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            "name text not null, " +
            "venue text not null, " +
            "comments text not null, " +
            "date text not null);";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBManager(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    //embedded class
    public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        //context refers to activity that called it
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            /*
            //taken from YouTube Tutorial video
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("drop table if exists Concert_Info");
            onCreate(db);*/
        }
    }

    public DBManager open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE + ";");
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    public long getId(String name)
    {
        long x = 10;
        return x;
    }
    public long insertConcert(String name, String venue, String date, String comments)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(COL_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(COL_VENUE, venue);
        initialValues.put(COL_DATE, date);
        initialValues.put(COL_COMMENTS, comments);
        return db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteConcert(long ROW_ID)
    {
        return db.delete(DB_TABLE, COL_ROWID + "=" + ROW_ID, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllConcerts() {
        return db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]
                        {
                                COL_NAME,
                                COL_VENUE,
                                COL_DATE,
                                COL_COMMENTS
                        },
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
    }

    public Cursor getConcert(long ROW_ID) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]
                        {
                                COL_ROWID,
                                COL_NAME,
                                COL_VENUE,
                                COL_DATE,
                                COL_COMMENTS
                        },
                        COL_ROWID + "=" + ROW_ID,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
        if (mCursor != null)
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        return mCursor;

    }

    public boolean updateConcert(String name, String venue, String date, String comments)
    {
        ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
        updateValues.put(COL_NAME, name);
        updateValues.put(COL_VENUE, venue);
        updateValues.put(COL_DATE, date);
        updateValues.put(COL_COMMENTS, comments);
        return db.update(DB_TABLE, updateValues, COL_NAME  + "=" + name, null) > 0;
    }

    public void reset () throws SQLException {
        db.delete(DB_TABLE, null, null);
        db.close();
        this.DBHelper.onCreate(this.db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncing a ListView with a set of data from a database can be very tricky.
Basically, everytime you know that the datas from your database have been modified, you need te requery them, update the adapter with the new data and finally call onDataSetChanged().

I suggest you to use a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html), that's an adapter that automatically filled your list with result from a Cursor (a SQLiteCursor for example).

Comment: Thanks for your response! If I switch to using the CursorAdapter will notifyDataSetChanged() work? Are there other methods I will have to implement to get the desired functionality or will it all work automatically

Answer (score 0):

Because you are querying on COL_ROWID = "_id",

```
db.delete(DB_TABLE, COL_ROWID + "=" + ROW_ID, null) > 0;
```

which is,

```
_id integer primary key autoincrement,
```

So once you have deleted the row it is showing no data(yet _id exist).

What you can do is that, in your onListItemClick, find _id by querying with string and pass it on.

Comment: thanks for the response! I tried what you suggested and I'm still having a similar problem. The incorrect entry dissapears and now the app force closes and gives me an out of bounds exception when I select some of the others as there is an out of bounds exception. This is because it is trying to select an index of 0

Comment: try {
            Cursor c = db.getConcert(position);
            String string_id = c.getString(0);
            Intent i =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewArtist.class);
            i.putExtra("id", string_id);
            startActivity(i);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: What I suggested previously is different then you have implemented.

Any way, another solution is that, inside onListItemClick get string value like this concertList.getItem(position); and pass it instead _id and just make changes on your query.

Comment: Apologies I thought I had correctly done what you suggested. Is my new code not finding the id (position 0) and passing it to the viewArtist activity? The viewArtist activity contains code to convert it to a long

Comment: Also just to be clear, is your second solution suggestion to pass edit the DBManager.getconcert() method to pass the name string as a parameter rather than the long row_id?